# How to show images by name (prefix)

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, select, css-selectors

How to show in block only images which name have some text like "small". To show only  picture2_small.gif and picture4_small.gif. And in another block show all of 'em.

```
<div class="small_images">
  <img src="picture1.gif" />
  <img src="picture2_small.gif" />
  <img src="picture3.gif" />
  <img src="picture4_small.gif" />
</div>

<div class="all_images">
  <img src="picture1.gif" />
  <img src="picture2_small.gif" />
  <img src="picture3.gif" />
  <img src="picture4_small.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry - I created project based on your solution coz no js is used )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the below selectors

`img[src$='small.gif']` - to display only images whose `src` **ends with** `small.gif`

or

`img[src*='small']` - to display only images which **contain** the word small in its `src`.

**Using CSS**

```
.small_images img[src$='small.gif']{
    display: block;
}
/* or */

.small_images img[src*='small']{
    display: block;
}
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$('.small_images img[src$="small.gif"]').show();
/* or */
$('.small_images img[src$="small.gif"]').css('display','block');

/* or */

$('.small_images img[src*="small"]').show();
/* or */
$('.small_images img[src*="small"]').css('display','block');
```

---

**Additional Info:** (based on your change to the question)

Adding `.small_images` would make sure that the `display` is set to only those `img` tags that are present under the element with `class='small_images'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the selector

```
$('img[src*="_small"]').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the ones with small and hide the others try,

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('img').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);
    if($img.attr("src").indexOf("small")!=-1){
        $img.show();
    }else{
        $img.hide();
    }
});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KcYk/

Answer (score 0):

Simple;

you may use;

```
<div class="small_images">
<img src="picture1.gif" />
<img src="picture2_small.gif" />
<img src="picture3.gif" />
<img src="picture4_small.gif" />
</div>
```

and for images inside div, use styling like;

```
.small_images img{
    display: none;
}
```

Then in your javascript, show images having text like "small", you have mentioned using;

```
$('img[src*="small"]').show();
```

Here is a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QkBdB/)**